# JAMA: Matrix.times() vs Matrix.arrayTimes()

Tags: java, matrix, matrix-multiplication, jama

Whats the difference between JAMA: Matrix.times() vs Matrix.arrayTimes() in JAMA (a java library for matrix calculations)

If I have a `d` dimension vector `x` and a `k` dimension vector `z` and I want to get the `xz^T` (x into z transpose) should I use Matrix.times or Matrix.arrayTimes?

How can I calculate this multiplication using JAMA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arrayTimes is simply element by element multiplication

C[i][j] = A[i][j] * B[i][j];

(treated as corresponding individual numbers)

while times is the matrix multiplication
where each element of the product is the sum of the products of corresponding row-columns.

The dimensions must match as per what you want to achieve.

Given your problem of x z^T the only viable solution is to turn these into dx1 and kx1 matrices respectively and perform x.times(z.transpose()). The result will be  a matrix of d x k dimensions.